# Inverse of Filter not yielding opposite results (Excel)

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2007

I have a file with about 85,000 rows (records).  I applied a filter to the file and filtered for only 34 items in a specific column and got about 15,000 records.  Now when I try to filter the same column NOT including those 34 items (Tot items - 34), I only get about 30,000 records instead of the expected 70,000.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Using Excel 2007...

Comment: What kind of values are you filtering on ? Text, numeric?

Comment: Are you using Autofilter or a table? Are you sure your filter is applied to the whole range?

Comment: I am filtering text values, using autofilter.  I am sure it is applied to the whole range.  I tried taking the unique list of items I wanted to filter by, added a column where i did a vlookup of the column of items vs the unique item list, and filtered out the N/A's and got 15,000 and 70,000 when I filtered for the N/A's only.

Comment: Are you saying you have #NA errors in the column you're filtering on?  If yes, can you adjust your formulas to suppress those errors?

Answer (score 0):

"In Excel 2007-Excel 2010, the limitation of the amount of entries in the  AutoFilter list is 10,000. If you have more than 10,000 unique items in the list, only the first 10,000 items appear." http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295971. ie seems you may only actually be filtering on some of the "non 34", whose average incidence is about 3.